# Finding integrals to solve second-order trigonometric/exponential differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I go about finding a particular integral when solving second-order differential equations involving a combination of trigonometric and exponential functions?

I know how to do them when (for example) it's $y''-3y'+2y=e^x$ and $y'-3y''+2y=\cos2x$. What would I do for, say, $y''-3y'-2y= 4e^{2x}\cos3x$?

Answer (score 0):

the particular solution of $y''-3y'-2y= 4e^{2x}\cos3x$ is
$$y_p=e^{2x}(A\cos 3x+B\sin 3x)$$

Comment: I have an example where its y''-6y'+25y=(4e^2x)(cos3x) I worked out the C.F as y=e^3x(Acos4x+Bsin4x) but am having trouble finding the particular integral so I can obtain the general solution

Comment: @James sorry where is your problem? In particular solution only?

Comment: how would you go about solving the question y''-6y'+25y=4(e^2x)(cos3x) I got as far as y=e^3x(Acos4x+Bsin4x)

Comment: $y'=e^{3 x} (A (3 cos(3 x)-3 sin(3 x))+B (3 cos(3 x)+3 sin(3 x)))$ and $y''=e^{3 x} (18 B cos(3 x)-18 A sin(3 x))$

Comment: then substitute them  in original differential equation to find the constant $A$ and $B$

Comment: what would y be for the substitution when subbing back into y''-3y'-2y=4e^2x(cos3x)

Comment: $y=e^{3x}(A\cos 3x+B\sin 3x)$

Comment: Does it not matter than whats infront of the e on the right hand side 4e^2xcos3x will it always be y=e^3x(Acos3x+Bsin3x) shouldn't it be y=Ae^3x(Bcos3x+sin3x)